Is there any advantage to using gifts to avoid estate tax?
The estate tax and gift tax are unified. Over the exemption there is no advantage in gifting, any tax advice there is only an advantage if you evade taxes.
Under the exemption there is theoretically a limit where you could transfer without taxes. However, the annual limit is very low and functionally renders the gift strategy impossible. For example, if you transfer 20k over 30 years that is less than the value of a house- most people who pay for college, inherit a house etc end up transferring well over the gift limit and because tuition is already exempt and the home is under mortgage there is rarely any advantage of the gift strategy.
Is there any practical case where the gift tax can be used to avoid estate tax or is most advice in this direction a form of tax evasion and legalese because the annual exemption is too low to matter?


Is there any practical case where the gift tax can be used to avoid
estate taxes?

Yes. There are many, although "avoid" isn't really the right word. You reduce combined gift and estate taxes.

Crummey Life insurance trusts. The annual exemption together which what is known as a Crummey Trust (after the U.S. v. Crummey case that established the legality of this method) allows a donor to fund, for example, life insurance premiums, which makes the face value of life insurance that would otherwise be included in the taxable estate of a decedent tax free. An annual gift of $18,000 a year to a Crummey Trust (drafted consistently with the controlling court case) could fund a term life insurance policy with a face value of about $13.5 million for a reasonably healthy insured. The payout of the face amount of the life insurance trust at the death of the insured is income tax, gift tax, and estate tax free. This does require that a lot of paperwork (called a Crummey notice) be done in the correct way each year. But, if the same policy were owned outright by the insured, the $13.5 million face value of the life insurance policy would have been included in the insured's estate for estate tax purposes, and if the insured has $14 million of other assets, the insured estate tax liability on the life insurance proceeds would be $5.4 million. Drafting the trust and managing it would cost something on the order of a few thousands dollars and the life insurance premium would be the same in each scenario.

Appreciation shifting. Suppose you make a $1,000,000 gift in excess of the annual exclusion and other exclusions in 2024 into an irrevocable trust that does not benefit the donor. This reduces the lifetime gift and estate tax exclusion from about $13 million to $12 million left over. Ten years later, the cash has been invested in growth stocks that pay no dividends but are now worth $10,000,000. But, then, the $9,000,000 of unrealized capital gain appreciation in this $1,000,000 inside the trust is not subject to estate taxation at death and does not count against his lifetime gifts and estate tax exclusion beyond the initial $1,000,000. So, he leaves his other $12,000,000+ to his heirs at death in addition to the trust, gift and estate tax free. Without the trust, the donor would have owed $3.6 million of estate taxes at death. See, e.g., here. This strategy is also sometimes called an "estate freeze."

Tax inclusive v. tax exclusive tax rates. If you make a gift more than  three years before your death and it is subject to gift taxes because you have made more than the $13 millionish exclusion from git and estate taxes already, this is taxed for gift tax purposes on a tax exclusive basis. So, suppose you make a gift of $1,000,000 in 2020 after having exhausted your gift and estate tax exclusion with prior gifts. Your tax is $400,000 and the donee gets $1,000,000 after tax. But, suppose that you make a gift of $1,400,000 at death after having exhausted your gift and estate tax exclusion. The tax is $560,000 and the beneficiary gets just $840,000 after tax, which is $160,000 more of taxes due, even though the reduction in the donor's estate is the same. So, if you are going to pay gift and estate taxes at all, it is much better to make the gift more than three years prior to death, rather than at death. (Gifts made within three years of death are retroactively treated for estate tax purposes as if they were made at death.) *See, e.g., this Congressional Research Service report.

Minority interest discounts and legally allowed (required) inconsistent valuation dates. Walt, a widower, owns a chain of movie theaters and WaltCo is a corporation with 300 shares with equal voting and economic rights. In August of 2020, while a lockdown is still in place, he hires a professional auctioneer to try to sell them, in a commercially reasonable manner, subject to a reserve price of $3,000,000. The highest price offered for it is $2,700,000 and the movie theater chain isn't solid. Walt instead gives 100 shares of WaltCo to his son Micky in addition to the annual exclusion amount of cash, and 100 shares of WaltCo to his daughter Minnie in addition to the annual exclusion amount of cash, retaining 100 shares for himself. Walt files a gift tax return (Form 709) supported by a report from a certified and licensed business appraiser. He reports a gift worth $600,000 of non-exempt gifts to Mickey, reflecting a 33.3% minority interest discount, and a gift worth $600,000 of non-exempt gifts to Minnnie, also reflecting a 33.3% minority interest discount (the discounts are ratified by the appraiser with an extensive report). Walt's lifetime gift and estate exclusion is reduced by $1,200,000 as a result. Four years later, Walt dies and the movie theater chain as a whole is valued by a licensed, certified business appraiser at $9,000,000, with Walt's 100 shares valued at $2,000,000 reflecting a 33.3% minority interest discount (half to Micky and half to Minnie). Walt has other assets worth $10,410,000 which are left to various people at his death, all of which is reported on his estate tax return (IRS Form 706). Walt pays no gift or estate tax at death. But, he has transferred $19,410,000 (plus annual exclusion gifts for many years) to his two children combined, when valued as of the date of his death. If he had made all of these gifts at death, he would have owed about $2.4 million in estate taxes. See, e.g., this law review article.


There are many other kinds of gifting strategies to reduce combined gift and estate taxes, but these are four examples of them.

is most advice in this direction a form of tax evasion and legalese
because the annual exemption is too low to matter?

No.
All are 100% legal and are fully disclosed to the IRS.
In some cases, gift taxes are actually paid to the IRS upon the transfer.
For people who will have less than $13 million of assets to donate during life and at death combined, however, gifts are usually a bad idea from a tax perspective since it tends to increase capital gains taxes over the long run.
